# C# Using String.Format to write data to txt in in a grid format

Tags: c#, string.format

Currently I'm trying to create a grid of data (maybe grid isn't the right word, will show later) using String.Format, now it would be fine on a normal basis except one of the lines could potentially have any number of lines.

The code currently looks roughly like this:

```
var TextFormat = "{0,-30} {1,-5} {2,-5} {3,-5} {4,-20}";
Text += String.Format(TextFormat, "Name", "ID", "Rarity", "Attributes", "Tier");
for(int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
{
    var Name = Items[i].Name;
    var ID = Items[i].Id;
    var Rarity = Items[i].Rarity;
    var Attributes = Items[i].Attributes.ToList();
    var Tier = Items[i].Tier;
    Text += String.Format(TextFormat, Name, ID, Rarity, Attributes[0], Tier);
}
```

Basically `Attributes[0]` is hardcoded as such just for display purposes to ensure formatting was fine in terms of spacing, but ultimately I'd like to have `Attributes` print multiple lines, so the output would be like this:

```
Name      ID     Rarity    Attributes    Tier
Sword     0      Common    Damage +2     0
                           Accuracy +1

Shield    1      Common    Defense +5    0
                           Weight +5
```

I was hoping to use `String.Format` for ease of spacing and not having to have a uniform number of spaces in between each one, and I'm having difficulty finding a usage of `String.Format` that is similar to what I'm looking for.

If it's not possible that's fine, I was just hoping there was a good solution that I'm just not seeing.

Comment: For starters, you should be using `StringBuilder` but it's do-able alright. You need an inner loop to keep adding lines for the Attributes column before moving to the next `Item`

Comment: So, what is the problem that you're having?  Are your lines not spaced correctly?  What font are you using for display (or print)?

Comment: The issue I'm encountering is that if I do any kind of new line it doesn't format properly, it'll just shoot to the next line and be left-aligned on the page. I'm not using anything special in terms of font, just whatever the default is for a .txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this would accomplish your goals? Just adding a loop to go over the rest of the attributes. Starting the loop at `i=1` will skip the first entry that you already output.

Also, you should consider the `StringBuilder` comment added by @DiskJunky above.

```
var TextFormat = "{0,-30} {1,-5} {2,-5} {3,-5} {4,-20}";
Text += String.Format(TextFormat, "Name", "ID", "Rarity", "Attributes", "Tier");
for(int i = 0; i < Items.Count; i++)
{
    var Name = Items[i].Name;
    var ID = Items[i].Id;
    var Rarity = Items[i].Rarity;
    var Attributes = Items[i].Attributes.ToList();
    var Tier = Items[i].Tier;
    Text += String.Format(TextFormat, Name, ID, Rarity, Attributes[0], Tier);
    for(int i=1; i<Attributes.Count; i++){
        Text += String.Format(TextFormat, "", "", "", Attributes[i], "");
    }
}
```

Comment: I was not aware I could do things like `String.Format(TextFormat, "", "", "", Attributes[i], "");` so that's pretty cool, I'll give it a whirl and see how it works out, thanks!

Comment: This was exactly what I needed, all I had to add was `"\n" +` in front of `TextFormat` in the loop. Thanks again!